# Commerce Email email doesn't send to admin with anonymous checkout

Tags: commerce, rules, emails

I want to be able to place the line items from the customer's order into an email to the admin, but not the user themselves. The built in option in DC doesn't have a token for the line items after submission. The Commerce Emails module solves the line item problem by providing a token for those line items, but the module doesn't send out an email to the admin user when an anonymous user submits the cart. See the issues in  https://drupal.org/node/2030233.

How would I go about setting up a Rule that hooks into the email function in the Commerce Email module? I didn't see any obvious functions that specified the recipients, so I'm a little lost as to where to proceed from here. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is this still the case?  I was just about to switch to using Commerce Emails, but if they don't send for anonymous checkout orders, that's a deal breaker for me.

Comment: Haven't messed with this for awhile, will report later.